# Issue overlaying anything above VideoPreviewLayer | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I have the following View Controller that displays a camera view and allows the user to scans various type of barcodes. The issue I am having is displaying a UIView on top of this view that sticks out of the bottom of the screen.

I have tried doing the following to have the UIView display but nothing seems to display it:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width - 10, height: 10))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

This view controller simply displays a camera view, so I do not understand what I am having issues displaying any views above it.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?

    public var overlayColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    public var borderWidth: Float = 5


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        // Check if captureDevice returns a value and unwrap it
        if let captureDevice = captureDevice {

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                guard let captureSession = captureSession else { return }
                captureSession.addInput(input)

                let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
                captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

                captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: .main)
                captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.code128, .qr, .ean13,  .ean8, .code39] //AVMetadataObject.ObjectType

                captureSession.startRunning()

                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
                view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            } catch {
                print("Error Device Input")
            }
        }


        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let overlayPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)

        let overlayWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 80 * 0.01;
        let x: CGFloat = view.bounds.width/2 - overlayWidth/2;
        let y: CGFloat = view.bounds.height/2 - overlayWidth/2 + 44;

        let transparentPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: overlayWidth, height: overlayWidth))
        overlayPath.append(transparentPath);
        overlayPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.path = overlayPath.cgPath;
        fillLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd;
        fillLayer.fillColor =  UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)

        let lineHeight = overlayWidth/4

        //for top left corner
        let path1 = UIBezierPath()
        path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+lineHeight, y: y))

        let path2 = UIBezierPath()
        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y+lineHeight))
        path1.append(path2)

        //for top right corner
        let path3 = UIBezierPath()
        path3.move(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y))
        path3.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y+lineHeight))
        path1.append(path3)

        let path4 = UIBezierPath()
        path4.move(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y))
        path4.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth-lineHeight,y: y))
        path1.append(path4)

        //for bottom right
        let path5 = UIBezierPath()
        path5.move(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path5.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y+overlayWidth-lineHeight))
        path1.append(path5)

        let path6 = UIBezierPath()
        path6.move(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path6.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+overlayWidth-lineHeight,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path1.append(path6)


        //for bottom left
        let path7 = UIBezierPath()
        path7.move(to: CGPoint(x: x,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path7.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x+lineHeight,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path1.append(path7)

        let path8 = UIBezierPath()
        path8.move(to: CGPoint(x: x,y: y+overlayWidth))
        path8.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x,y: y+overlayWidth-lineHeight))
        path1.append(path8)

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = path1.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
        layer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.square
        layer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.bevel
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.strokeColor = overlayColor.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = .high

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.75, green:0.16, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]


        view.addSubview(codeLabel)
        codeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        codeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        codeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        codeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //navigationItem.title = "Scanner"
        view.backgroundColor = .white


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let codeLabel:UILabel = {
        let codeLabel = UILabel()
        codeLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        codeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return codeLabel
    }()

    let codeFrame:UIView = {
        let codeFrame = UIView()
        codeFrame.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        codeFrame.layer.borderWidth = 2
        codeFrame.frame = CGRect.zero
        codeFrame.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return codeFrame
    }()

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            //print("No Input Detected")
            codeFrame.frame = CGRect.zero
            codeLabel.text = "No Data"
            return
        }

        let metadataObject = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        guard let stringCodeValue = metadataObject.stringValue else { return }

        view.addSubview(codeFrame)

        guard let barcodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObject) else { return }
        codeFrame.frame = barcodeObject.bounds
        codeLabel.text = stringCodeValue

        captureSession?.stopRunning()

    }


    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the things I've done in the past is to put the camera preview in to it's own `UIView`, this is then added to the `UIViewController` along with all the other controls I might want to use.  This provides me with a greater level of control over how the z-ordering works

Comment: Can you please show how you would put the following camera preview in a UIView? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Well, you've actually already done it.  Instead of starting with a `UIViewController`, start with a `UIView` and then `view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)` would become `layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)`.  You'd need to manually load this view and add it, but you've already done that as well

Comment: I'm sorry I am still a bit confused, so I have `view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)` and `layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)` should I be calling the in viewdidload some other way?

Comment: `UIViewController` has an inbuilt `UIView` which it controls - this is `view`.  You need to create your own `UIView`, onto which you attach your camera view, just like you have already done, but instead of using the view controller's view, you use your custom view.  Then, in the view controller you add all the views you want to the controllers view